# Ble disconnect 133

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm having issues with random disconnects caused by the Android BLE stack.

Right after calling `device.connectGatt` I receive a disconnect with status 133 in my `onConnectionStateChange` method.
I've tested this on multiple devices running all kinds of Android versions and it happens on most of them. (More or less frequently)

I read about other cases where this behaviour seems to be caused by too many requests or faulty registered indications, but in my case there isn't even an active connection before the disconnect happens. Also I made sure nothing else but the connect request was sent to the device before this happens.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

BLE support on "old" Android  version can be quite hazardous, and BLE mechanisms are not easy to grasp.

I had the same issue as you did. I'm currently using [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle), but it's basically a wrapper for the OS APIs, and highly facilitate the work, so I recommend it.

There are some things that you must remember when dealing with BLE: 

 - One command at a time

 - Always close connections

On older version, you have to (quite mystically) set the `boolean autoConnect` parameter to true when trying to connect to a device while you are not scanning.

 I just wasn't able to connect on my BLE device with Android < 6, set this parameter, and voilà, the magic happened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I'm actually really careful already when it comes to closing and removing existing connections. Also I've tried to keep everything as synchronous as possible so there's no way a connection could be used by multiple threads. 

But I'll give `autoConnect` a try and see what happens.

Comment: Just let me now :) If it doesn't, I can set up a small sample project with RxAndroidBle that works for me and share it with you, so that you can test with it.
You could also add specificities about the BLE device you are trying to connect to: is there any pairing/bonding? is it another Android device? What is the Gatt Profile used?